# cpu temperature is higher than usual after installing xubuntu

Tags: drivers, cpu

I have installed Xubuntu 14.04 on Asus S550CB but the system becomes warmer than usual. So I tried to configure **lm-sensors** and saw cpu temperature is about 50 degrees. I guessed that some drivers are not installed and run

```
lshw -html > system.html && xdg-open ./system.html
```

Then I noticed that 3 drivers are red. Does it mean they are not installed? Those drivers were:

1)id: generic:0

Description: signal processing controller

2) id: serial

Description: SMBus

3) id: generic:1

Description: signal processing controller

Now if it means that they are not installed, how can I search for them and install them? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What made you think it's the missing driver? Do you see any process that continuously consume 100% cpu (using top or ps)?

Comment: @SoumyadipDM Because I had similar experience in Windows 8.1 and when I installed "thermal driver of cpu" every thing was fine. By the way, consumption of cpu is usual (about 1 or 2%).